# Create multiple JQuery datepicker in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am trying to create multiple jquery date pickers in my page.  I have 2 text-boxes and i want to reference these date-pickers so how can i do that?
the first datepicker

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: -2, maxDate: -0 });
     });
    </script>
```

2nd datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: -2 });
      });
    </script>
```

here are my texboxes

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" placeholder="Select date"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" placeholder="Select date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: use different `classname`

Comment: try using ClientIDMode="static", then you can reference them with the CSS selectors "#textbox1" and "#textbox2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either give each textbox a unique css class.

Or just refference the IDs in jQuery like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#textbox1').datepicker({ minDate: -2, maxDate: -0 });
       $('#textbox2').datepicker({ minDate: -2});
     });
</script>
```

Just make sure to set ClientIDMode to static:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" placeholder="Select date"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" placeholder="Select date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or you can reference them like so without setting ClientIDMode to static:

```
$('#<%= textbox2.ClientID %>').datepicker({ minDate: -2});
```